# Formatting issue with JsonSlurper

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the following JSON response.

```
{
  "data": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "success": true,
    "technicalSettings": [
      {
        "name": "Abcd Advanced",
        "humanoid": "adult",            
        "uid": "1da67bdc-0173-1000-0000-53f11ba5a31e",
        "technicalSettingsUID": "1dae2bdc-0173-1000-0000-53uj91ba5a31e",
        "checksum": "101a1ddf3f59c4e666dadc9677bf998c78216e8e8d79882e8b0d19ddb77e",
        "protocolNumber": "",
        "modifiedDate": "Tue, 21 Jul 2020 04:06:03 GMT",        
        "version": 1,
        "protocolUID": "df26c1fc-328e-43b6-b285-e0671267dae1",
        "dependencies": [
          "rawprotocols/1dae2bdc-0173-1000-0000-53f11ba5a31e.zip"
        ],
        "deviationChecksum": {
          "subsectionChecksum": [
            
          ],
          "aggregatedDeviationChecksum": "101a1ddf3f59c4e6bgtydc9bdad55abf998c78216e8e8d79882e8b0d19ddb77e"
        },
        "protocolmetadata": {
          "MRSessionData": {
            "entry": "Feet First",
            "fieldstrength": "30000",
            "gradcoil": "11",
            "position": "Supine",
            "MR_VERSION": "DV26.0#2",
            "autostart": "0",
            "srrating": "120",
            "tabentry": "None"
          }
        },
        "clinicalInstructions": [
          
        ],
        "population": "adult"
      }
    ],
    "library": {
      "vsion": 5,
      "dmVersion": 3
    }
  },
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "error": ""
}
```

I'm using the JSON extractor to fetch the values of data.technicalSettings.

[image]

Now when I use the values in the variable pPublishTechSettings with the JsonSlurper,even though I get all the values, the order of the values are different in the string strPublishTechSettings. How can I get the values in the same order as in the original response JSON?

Here is my code.

```
def technicalSettings = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('pPublishTechSettings_ALL'))

technicalSettings.eachWithIndex { setting, index ->  

  strPublishTechSettings =   new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(setting).toString()  

  log.info('Values' + ': ' + strPublishTechSettings )
         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any guarantee on the order of the extracted elements given you're using JSON Extractor, it happens under the hood of [JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Given you're using Groovy you can get rid of this JSON Extractor bit and move everything to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor):

```
def technicalSettings = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.technicalSettings

technicalSettings.eachWithIndex { setting, index ->
    strPublishTechSettings =   new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(setting).toString()
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)